# How to do an auto approval if the admin creates the calendar event

Tags: sharepoint-online

Problem: I am the admin of a calendar. I have people request time slots and I need to approve them.

Sometimes I, admin, create events.

Right now it emails me and then I have to approve them, well technically it emails me three times.

How do I create a workflow where IF the admin creates a "task" it is automatically approved, no emails?

I know nothing about SharePoint. I can't really seem to find anything that teaches about this program either.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the workflow to be run automatically when an item is created/edit, the created By/Modified by user will be the workflow Initiator. If the workflow is run manually, the initiator is the user who run it.

We can get the current user (Initiator) from Workflow Context data source.
[image]

If the initiator is not admin (you), start Approval process on the current item.
[image]

Another method to auto-approve approval task is, create a se SharePoint 2013 workflow for the workflow task list of the approval workflow and check if the workflow task is created by the admin (you). If the workflow task is created by admin (you), set the Task Outcome to Approved. Check [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8149e06e-499c-40e6-b9d9-bba54c950926/can-anyone-confirm-my-designer-workflow-autoapprove-finding?forum=sharepointcustomization) for more information.

Comment: Where do I do this?  I am using the Online version and I don't see this option in WorkFlow Settings.

Comment: It is a SharePoint Designer workflow created by SharePoint Designer 2013. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo